# Following tutorial and android compiler is jumping straight to 'OnFailure' error message

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am following this tutorial:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/android-extract-data-from-json-array-using-retrofit-library-with-jetpack-compose/

I am trying to follow the tutorial to programmatically create a drop down list based on a JSON response from a server. Can someone suggest a suitable alternative that does not use XML pages?

although the program compiles with no errors, I seem to only get the functionality of the TOAST at the end of the code telling me "Fail to get the data"

```
override fun onFailure(call: Call<ArrayList<ListModal>?>, t: Throwable) {
            // displaying an error message in toast
            Toast.makeText(ctx, "Fail to get the data..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show()
```

I have tried the recreating the app multiple times on multiple devices, both Android API's 21 through to 34 and still getting the same issue. Can anyone suggest what the problem may be, are the references deprecated in some way? Is retrofit still used?

Answer (score 0):

This is an excellent article and very useful for what I was looking for
https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html (Section 5.1)

Android provides specialized fragment and activity classes to simplify list handling.

The classes are the ListActivity class, if you want to use lists in activities, and the ListFragment class, if you want to use lists in fragments.

You do not have to assign a layout to these elements. If you do not define a layout, the activity or fragment contains a single ListView by default. ListActivity and ListFragment also allow you to override a onListItemClick() method for handling selection of list items.

Both classes allow you to set the adapter to the default ListView via the setListAdapter() method.

The following example code shows a simple ListFragment implementation.